# Is there a word for "types of nouns"?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, phrase-requests, parts-of-speech

I know "parts of speech" is used to mean nouns, adjectives, verbs, etc., but is there a word or phrase for "types of nouns" that would include subject, direct object, indirect object, etc.?

Comment: *Noun* is a word classification. I am not aware of *nouns* that can only be used as a subject vs. *nouns* that can only be used as an object (other than certain pronouns).

Comment: Are nouns used as anything else besides subjects, direct objects, and indirect objects? For example, in the sentence "Katie gave John a present at her house," _Katie_ is the subject, _John_ is the indirect object, and _present_ is the direct object. What classification is the noun _house_?

Comment: *At her house* is a *prepositional phrase*, where *her house* is the complement (object of) the preposition *at*. *Her house* is called a *noun phrase*, and *her* is a determiner for the noun *house*.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I wasn't sure of the exact terminology.

Comment: I think those are called 'functions' of the noun.

Comment: As a sentence element "at her house" is an adverbial or better an adverbial sentence element. A sentence has apart from the VE (verbal element) primary elements (you ask who/ whom/ what) and secondary elements giving special circumstances (you ask when/where/why/how etc). The secondary elements are traditionally called adverbials. The term prepositional phrase is not a sentence element, it only describes the structure of a word group beginning with a preposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various terms for the parts of a sentence (Oxford Guide to English Grammar: subject, verb, object, complement, adverbial): sentence parts, sentence elements, constituents.

By the way "verb" is a word class, so it is no good and precise term for the SE (sentence element). Verb part or verb element would be better. Likewise, adverbial is used as word class for adverb groups. So, in order to have a precise term for the SE adverbial part/element would be better.

Answer (score 1):

After some more research, it seems like [**noun functions**](http://www.english-for-students.com/Noun-Functions.html) is commonly  used to include all the things a noun can be, including subject, direct object, indirect object, prepositional object, etc.